Is it possible to send a sms text to someones iphone and make it appear that they replied to a number that they did not reply to?
I received a text from a number on my iphone that I do not recognize and the strange thing is is that there is no conversation thread. The only text showing looks like it came from my phone replying back to them saying Hi with an emoji after the Hi. It is very odd because it looks like it was me who replied but I did not. And there was no prior message before this Hi, only the Hi coming from my end.
Is it possible to send a text to someone and make it appear that they replied to this unknown number?


That does sound spooky - I've never seen a text like that before. Is this a programming question, though? You might get better replies on [apple.se] if you ask over there.

For anyone else reading: Link to the new question

Go to the link @Holo posted. It is carried over to there.
